# how to apply css style only to homepage

Tags: php, html, css, smf-forum

So I have a SMF forum and I need to apply a background image only to the homepage. when I just simply add the style to the .body it does change the homepage background but also change in other sections as well, eg: forums boards and posts. So I just only want to display the background image on the homepage and it should not apply to the other forum sections. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.
Simplest way to do this is to add a class in homepage body element.

```
<html>
---
<body class="has-background-img">
---
---
</body>
```

further, remove this class from other pages where you do not want background image to appear.

Comment: thanks. how should I add this class to the index.php ?

Comment: simply open index.php in your text-editor and add the class in body. further, put the css in your style.css for background image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background only on your homepage, it's better you use the inline styling method.

```
<html>
...
...
<body style="background-image: url("gradient_bg.png");">
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

[CSS Background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)
[CSS How to](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)